# IOS Spritekit: Circle outline not showing

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode

In the below the yellow circle does not show in the IOS emulator.  If I add the setFillColor which is currently commented out, then I get a red circle.

Why does the outline of the shape not show?
Is there a way to trigger the outline?

```
-(void)addTargetNode2 {
    float radius=90;
    SKShapeNode *targetOuter = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius];
    //[targetOuter setFillColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [targetOuter setStrokeColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [targetOuter setLineWidth:1];

    //Position the node.
    targetOuter.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));

    [self addChild:targetOuter];
}
```

I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312055/invisible-circle-stroke-color-in-skspritenode-ios) article - but no answer.

Edit:
I've got a working work-around... but not particularly fond of it.  Drawing a circle the color of the background over the top of a filled in circle:

```
-(void)addTarget {
    float radius=50;
    CGFloat borderWidth=3;

    //Draw the Circle.
    SKShapeNode *targetOuter = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius];
    [targetOuter setName:@"targetOuter"];
    [targetOuter setFillColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    //Following line should set the outline color but isn't working.
    //[targetOuter setStrokeColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [targetOuter setLineWidth:1];
    targetOuter.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),
                                      CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));        
    [self addChild:targetOuter];

    /* Work around
     Add a circle the color of the background to emulate an outline.
     Can be removed in targetOuter outline works.
    */
    SKShapeNode *targetInner = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:radius-borderWidth];
    [targetInner setFillColor:self.backgroundColor];
    targetInner.position = targetOuter.position;
    [self addChild:targetInner];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is a bug with the iOS simulator and SKShapeNode. I've been able to replicate this problem on simulator but never on device so you shouldn't worry to add a workaround.

iOS Simulator is good to test low framerate conditions and different screen sizes but, aside from that, not very reliable to test SpriteKit games overall.

Comment: Thanks - alas I'm not a licensed developer (yet), so can't test on hardware.  Thanks for confirming it still works on the hardware.  I'll move on and see if it's fixed in the future.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed.  I am now running xcode 6.1 and it's working.  Issue was with xcode 6.0.